# Problem getting 4K (UHD) output to Sony 65" 4K TV XBR-65X900A

Tags: resolution, hdmi, intel, sony

I think I have tried everything... but hoping someone here can show me I haven't tried everything.

I am unable to select or configure an output above 1080p on my Ubuntu machine.  I have tried latest Linux Intel Graphics on 12.04 LTS, then tried upgrading to 13.10 and also kernel 3.12.  I have also tried all manner of xrandr configuration without luck (either TV says not supported or Ubuntu chucks a spasm about CRT1 "no such interface" (when I am using HDMI).

When I read the EDID i do not get 4K information (but this seems not just SONY when I Google this problem I am having with 4K output) and read-edid says 1 more block was available but not decoded, possibly indicating a problem with the Intel drivers.

I am using Intel i5 with HD4000 GPU and HDMI output.

Below is the hopefully all the relevant info:

```
xrandr:
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1439mm x 809mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9     30.0     24.0     30.0     24.0
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0
   1280x1024      60.0
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     30.0     59.9     30.0     24.0     24.0
   1440x576i      50.1
   1024x768       60.0
   1440x480i      60.1     60.1
   800x600        60.3
   720x576        50.0
   720x480        60.0     59.9
   640x480        60.0     59.9
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 

uname -a
    Linux riker 3.12.0-031200-generic #201311031935 SMP Mon Nov 4 00:36:54 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:        13.10
Codename:       saucy

lspci | grep VGA:
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

get-edid: get-edid version 2.0.0

        Performing real mode VBE call
        Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f00 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
        Function supported
        Call successful

        VBE version 300
        VBE string at 0x11100 "Intel(R) Sandybridge/Ivybridge Graphics Chipset Accelerated VGA BIOS"

VBE/DDC service about to be called
        Report DDC capabilities

        Performing real mode VBE call
        Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
        Function supported
        Call successful

        Monitor and video card combination does not support DDC1 transfers
        Monitor and video card combination supports DDC2 transfers
        0 seconds per 128 byte EDID block transfer
        Screen is not blanked during DDC transfer

Reading next EDID block

VBE/DDC service about to be called
        Read EDID

        Performing real mode VBE call
        Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x1 cx=0x0
        Function supported
        Call successful

EDID claims 1 more blocks left


*********** Something special has happened!
Please contact the author, Matthew Kern
E-mail: pyrophobicman@gmail.com
Please include full output from this program (especially that to stderr)



Reading next EDID block

VBE/DDC service about to be called
        Read EDID

        Performing real mode VBE call
        Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x1 cx=0x0
        Function supported
        Call successful

EDID claims 1 more blocks left
EDID blocks left is wrong.
Your EDID is probably invalid.
parse-edid: EDID checksum passed.

        # EDID version 1 revision 3
Section "Monitor"
        # Block type: 2:0 3:fc
        Identifier "SONY TV  *07"
        VendorName "SNY"
        ModelName "SONY TV  *07"
        # Block type: 2:0 3:fc
        # Block type: 2:0 3:fd
        HorizSync 14-70
        VertRefresh 48-62
        # Max dot clock (video bandwidth) 150 MHz
        # DPMS capabilities: Active off:no  Suspend:no  Standby:no

        Mode    "1920x1080"     # vfreq 60.000Hz, hfreq 67.500kHz
                DotClock        148.500000
                HTimings        1920 2008 2052 2200
                VTimings        1080 1084 1089 1125
                Flags   "+HSync" "+VSync"
        EndMode
        Mode    "1280x720"      # vfreq 60.000Hz, hfreq 45.000kHz
                DotClock        74.250000
                HTimings        1280 1390 1430 1650
                VTimings        720 725 730 750
                Flags   "+HSync" "+VSync"
        EndMode
        # Block type: 2:0 3:fc
        # Block type: 2:0 3:fd
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the source of my problem.

The motherboard (ASUS H61M-A) does not support output on its HDMI port beyond 1200p.  So even though the GPU can do magical things, it seems the MB is still a bottle-neck and not just a  "pass-through" of the GPU capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

HDMI 1.4 doesn't support 4K/UHD, but HDMI 2.0 does.  Since you have a 4K TV, your TV should have a HDMI 2.0 port (typically 4K TVs have one of these, but they may all be HDMI 2.0).

Does your PC happen to have DisplayPort, Mini DisplayPort, or USB Type-C connectors?  If so, you could get an adapter to go from that to HDMI 2.0.

Having said that, it may or may not work.  If the TV supports 4:4:4 chroma, that means the video stream is uncompressed, which PCs can do.  But if it only supports 4:2:0 chroma (cheaper TVs, like my 4K Seiki), then you could probably run 4K from your PC to the TV, but at 30hz instead of the much better 60hz.